# How to embed a JSON object with arrays from MySQL ('Concat') into a EJS-File in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, ejs

For test purposes I have created a JSON object in the demo.js, which should be integrated in the ejs template.

If I do it like this, everything works fine within the ejs page.
But I create the JSON object dyn. from an SQL query (see below).

Here are my setup:

**demo.js**

```
function gameData() {

    return {
        id: 13,
        round: 1,
        user: [{
            id: 4711,
            player_id: 1,
            name: "John",
            value: 3,
            active: 1
        }, {
            id: 4712,
            player_id: 2,
            name: "Phil",
            value: 3,
            active: 0
        }]
    }
}

module.exports = {
    gameData: gameData
}
```

**app.js**

```
let gameDemo = require('./demo');

app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/game', {
        utils: gameDemo
    });
})
```

**ejs site**

```
<% utils.gameData().user.forEach(function(element, index, item){ %>
    <%= element.player_id %>
<% }); %>
```

Here I create a MySQL database (5.7) connection and get the JSON object as the result. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with that.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {

    ...

    db.getConnection((error, connection) => {
        
        let sqlQuery = `SELECT
                            CONCAT("{",
                            CONCAT("id:" , g.id, ","),
                            CONCAT("round:" , g.round, ","),
                            CONCAT("user:", "[",
                                GROUP_CONCAT(
                                CONCAT("{"),
                                    CONCAT("id:" , gd.id, ","),
                                    CONCAT("player_id:" , gd.player_id, ","),
                                    CONCAT("name:" , gd.name, ","),
                                    CONCAT("value:" , gd.value, ","),
                                    CONCAT("active:" , gd.active, ","),
                                CONCAT("}")
                                )
                            ,"]")
                            ,"}")
                        AS json FROM game_data gd
                            INNER JOIN games g
                            ON g.game_id = gd.game_id
                        WHERE gd.game_id = '235816ab-2ad8-41b2-8375-d980e207e43f'`

        connection.query(sqlQuery, (err,row, fields) => { 
        
            res.render('pages/game', {
                utils: row[0].json
            });

        })
        connection.release();

    })
     
 })
```

index.ejs

```
<% utils.gameData().user.forEach(function(element, index, item){ %>
     <%= element.player_id %>
<% }); %>
```

I get the error: *"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"*

If I call `<% = utils %>` in the ejs, I get the JSON object as a string.

Then I tried `JSON.parse(row[0].json)` and got *SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()*

`JSON.parse(result)` show the error *undefined:1 [object Object]*

Then i tried

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {

    ...

    db.getConnection((error, connection) => {
        
        let sqlQuery = `SELECT
                            CONCAT("{",
                            CONCAT("id:" , g.id, ","),
                            CONCAT("round:" , g.round, ","),
                            CONCAT("user:", "[",
                                GROUP_CONCAT(
                                CONCAT("{"),
                                    CONCAT("id:" , gd.id, ","),
                                    CONCAT("player_id:" , gd.player_id, ","),
                                    CONCAT("name:" , gd.name, ","),
                                    CONCAT("value:" , gd.value, ","),
                                    CONCAT("active:" , gd.active, ","),
                                CONCAT("}")
                                )
                            ,"]")
                            ,"}")
                        AS json FROM game_data gd
                            INNER JOIN games g
                            ON g.game_id = gd.game_id
                        WHERE gd.game_id = '235816ab-2ad8-41b2-8375-d980e207e43f'`

        connection.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => { 

            res.render('pages/game', {
                utils: result[0].json // JSON Object
            });

        })
        connection.release();

    })
     
 })
```

At the ejs file ill get a json object

```
console.log(<%= utils %>) // JSON Object in console OK
console.log(typeof <%= utils %>) // Object
```

If i create a variable in javascript area `let obj = <%= utils %>;` i have full access to the data.

But, how do I get any values from the array for ejs?

Comment: Can you include the structure of `utils` JSON object. I had kind of similar issue, and turned out the use of `[]` instead of dot `.` to access the vaule of the key helped.
 Example : `<p class="title-3"><b>Criteria:</b> <%=results[i]['search_filters']%></p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that if a query has "large" results (more then 10 key/val), the key/value pairs had sometimes a line break. See user key9. No error pattern recognizable.

Strange behavior of the results. The error occurs only once in the objects from the user array. But not every object is affected.

Extract from the sql result:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "round": 1,
    "user": [{
        "1": 8,
        "2": 9,
        "3": 10,
        "4": 0,
    "5": 8,
    "6": 9,
    "7": 10,
    "8": 0,
    "9": 
    8,
    "10": 9,
    "11": 10,
    "12": 0,
    "13": 8,
    "14": 9,
    "15": 10
    }]
}
```

**Solution**

I put the SQL query in double quotation marks and escaped it.
Parse the SQL result (type String) into an Object and that's it.

```
db.getConnection((error, connection) => {

    let sqlQuery = `SELECT
      CONCAT("{",
        CONCAT("\\"id\\":" , g.id, ","),
        CONCAT("\\"round\\":" , g.round, ","),
        CONCAT("\\"user\\":", "[",
            GROUP_CONCAT(
              CONCAT("{"),
                  CONCAT("\\"id\\":" , gd.id, ","),
                  CONCAT("\\"player_id\\":" , gd.player_id, ","),
                  CONCAT("\\"name\\":" , gd.name, ","),
                  CONCAT("\\"value\\":" , gd.value, ","),
                  CONCAT("\\"active\\":" , gd.active, ","),
              CONCAT("}")
            )
        ,"]")
      ,"}")
  AS json FROM game_data gd
  INNER JOIN games g ON g.game_id = gd.game_id
  WHERE gd.game_id = '235816ab-2ad8-41b2-8375-d980e207e43f'`

    connection.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {

        let stringRes = result[0].json
        let obj = JSON.parse(stringRes)

        res.render('pages/game', {
            gamedata: obj
        });

    })
    connection.release();

})
```

Now i have full access to the JSON-Object within the ejs file.

Values within the object: `<%= gamedata.id %>`

Values within the user-array: `<%= gamedata.user[0].player_id %>`

Values for each object within the user-array:

```
<% for (var i = 0, l = gamedata.user.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = gamedata.user[i];
%>
  <option value="<%= i %>"><%= obj.player_id %></option>
<% } %>
```